# Making an employee hours table

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting, tabular

I was wondering how to make a table in python 3 that has 7 columns for each day of the week and a variable defined amount of rows. I need to input employee hours for each separate person and be able to add them up later. This problem is really throwing me for a *loop*.

For example:

```
employeeAmount = int(input("Enter the amount of employees here"))
```

Then the table goes down "employeeAmount" of times.

I need something like this
    Employee 1 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 8| 0 | 9 | 7 |
    Employee 2 etc
    Employee 3 etc

Comment: You can use a database like `sqlite`

Comment: Can you please post your attempt?